# How can i receive a pairing request event via dbus, glib?

Tags: c, bluetooth, glib, bluez, pairing

I'm currently making a Bluetooth app with BlueZ

I need to get a Pairing request.
Using BlueZ DBus API, i've made my Agent into NoInputOutput mode, and i succeed the first pairing with my phone.

However, if i delete the linux device(which uses my bluetooth app that i am developing) from my phone and try to re-connect, i can't pair it together.

I searched Python code examples that...
From BlueZ's DBus API, calling RequestAuthorization method to pair and successes it, then deleting the device and re-pairing works fine.

But in case of smartphone's pairing request, i think i should call RequestAuthorization method WHEN SOME EVENT(S) is received. And i have no idea for that.

Conclusion: How can i get a pairing request event using dbus and glib loop?

I've already checked
[bluez pairing before exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403176/bluez-pairing-before-exchange)

apparently, gdbus is a combination of dbus and glib.
However, i'm using dbus and glib separated since i can sorted some codes that i do not need.
More, now i think it doesn't have any relations with deleting devices from the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bluez pairing before exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403176/bluez-pairing-before-exchange)

Comment: It would be useful if you could share some debugging information. To get debug information you can have `bluetoothctl`, `sudo btmon`, and `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez` in separate terminals.

Comment: The agent that you have registered is called by `bluetoothd` when it receives a pairing request. The `RegisterAgent` on `org.bluez.AgentManager1` is telling `bluetoothd` where to find the agent you have created. Depending what type of pairing request `bluetoothd` gets depends which of the methods from the [org.bluez.Agent1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt) API it will call.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.
i checked this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186562/bluez5-event-when-inbound-pairing-is-complete

According to this, whenever the pairing request is occurred, "InterfaceAdded" Signal is also occurred. This is the biggest hint that i ever got.